# Object not set to an instance of an object when editing a WPF datagrid combobox column when the column is sorted

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a Datagrid in which I use a TextColumn bound to an Integer Property.I can edit the the values in the TextColumn allright until I click the column header. The column will sort correctly when clicked but when I then try to edit a value afterwards I get an exception when I cause a LostFocus Event by clicking somewhere else.

(Question changed to the minimal required setup to make it reproducible)

The XAML:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CompStrength}"/>
```

The StackTrace:

```
bij System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.UpdateRowEditing(DataGridCell cell)
bij System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.OnExecutedCommitEdit(ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
bij System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.OnExecutedCommitEdit(Object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
bij System.Windows.Input.CommandBinding.OnExecuted(Object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
bij System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.ExecuteCommandBinding(Object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e, CommandBinding commandBinding)
bij System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.FindCommandBinding(CommandBindingCollection commandBindings, Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e, ICommand command, Boolean execute)
bij System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.FindCommandBinding(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e, ICommand command, Boolean execute)
bij System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.OnExecuted(Object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
bij System.Windows.UIElement.OnExecutedThunk(Object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
bij System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object target)
bij System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
bij System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
bij System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
bij System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
bij System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
bij System.Windows.Input.RoutedCommand.ExecuteImpl(Object parameter, IInputElement target, Boolean userInitiated)
bij System.Windows.Input.RoutedCommand.Execute(Object parameter, IInputElement target)
bij System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.EndEdit(RoutedCommand command, DataGridCell cellContainer, DataGridEditingUnit editingUnit, Boolean exitEditMode)
bij System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.OnCurrentCellChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
bij System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
bij System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
bij System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
bij System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
bij System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
bij System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetCurrentValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
bij System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.set_CurrentCellContainer(DataGridCell value)
bij System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.set_FocusedCell(DataGridCell value)
bij System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell.OnAnyGotFocus(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
bij System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
bij System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
bij System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
bij System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
bij System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnGotFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
```

Comment: Is the error originating in the converter or just coming from the .net framework?

Comment: @Josh The question was needlessly complicated. I reduced it now to the bare minimum. The error comes from the WPF Framework itself it seems when you look at the Stack Trace. The Stack Trace does not specify any methods that I have overridden in the first 20+ lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally tracked down the cause for this exception after painstakingly rebuilding the project: Surprisingly the error appears after adding the classc.xaml theme from PresentationFramework.Classic.dll as a resource to the WPF project.
I contacted Microsoft about this en we'll see what happens...

Comment: I produce the same exception when adding 'aero.normalcolor.xaml' from PresentationFramework.Aero. It seems that the DataGridCell loses its DataGridRow, the Property 'RowOwner' is null

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found the problem in my own case is in a callback from CellEditEnding event handler was trying to update grid data source, which caused the behavior. Add a flag to notice grid is being updated solved my problem